# calculate hours between 2 timestamps using excel pivot table

Tags: excel, datetime, pivot

i have a table like this:

```
user          |  sg_message_id         |   event         |   datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  delivered       | 04/13/2018 12:56:30
john player   |  ekjf939e9313140_34k    |  opened          | 04/15/2018 16:05:00
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  delivered       | 04/12/2018 18:45:21
cristian dior |  dsfsk0340344030fkjkj   |  opened          | 04/13/2018 15:40:17
```

For a **user**, for each unique **sg_message_id**, how do i create an Excel pivot table that can display hours elapsed between when an email was **delivered** and when it was **opened**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Calculated Item...` in your pivot table. If your data set is not that big. Follow this steps:

[image]

You can use **Power Query**. It is an add-in developed by Microsoft since Excel2010+ (by default in Excel2016 known as Get and Transform). There you can connect directly any type of source of data and edit it as you want.

Here an example for your case:

[image]

Comment: Thanks +virtualdvid. This is good, but yes i would like your help with the next solution.

Comment: BTW a little off topic - do you know if how the above calculated field can be added if its a google spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't have any idea. I have never used google for this :/. I updated my answer for Ms Excel.